# Intent does not send values from editText, android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a parameter **from** one activity (ActividadInsercionObjeto) **to** another **(DatosSensor)** using intents, but I have been trying with non exit. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The value I need to pass is the last value called **idObjeto** in the photo.jpg. This value comes from a SQLite which has been synchronized with remote MySql, so when the origin activity is opened, the values come inside of the fields.

When I press a button then the activity would have to take the value from `campoIdObjeto` which is the value of **"idObjeto in the photo"** and then it would have to send this value to sencond activity and show it in a toast.
 When I execute the app, it stops and send this message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null
>   object reference.

Photo:
[photoscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUV7.jpg)
I do not know why it does not take the value...

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks 
Oscar

**Activity origin**:

```
    public class ActividadInsercionObjeto extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, View.OnClickListener {

    // Referencias UI
    private EditText campodescripcionNombre;
    private EditText campoMarca;
    private EditText campoModelo;
    private EditText campoCorreo;
    private EditText campoIdObjeto;
    private Button accesodata;
    public final static String EXTRA_ID = "idObjeto";
    public EditText IdentidadObjeto;

    // Clave del uri del objeto como extra
    public static final String URI_OBJETO = "extra.uriObjeto";

    private Uri uriObjeto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_insercion_objeto);

        //agregarToolbar();

        // Encontrar Referencias UI
        campodescripcionNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_descripcion_nombre);
        campoMarca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_marca);
        campoModelo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_modelo);
        campoCorreo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_correo);
        campoIdObjeto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campo_idObjeto);


        accesodata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accesodata);
        accesodata.setOnClickListener(this);


        // Determinar si es detalle
        String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra(URI_OBJETO);
        if (uri != null) {
            setTitle(R.string.titulo_actividad_editar_objeto);
            uriObjeto = Uri.parse(uri);
            getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_insercion_objeto, menu);

        // Verificación de visibilidad acción eliminar
        if (uriObjeto != null) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.accion_eliminar).setVisible(true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.accion_confirmar:
                insertar();
                break;
            case R.id.accion_eliminar:
                eliminar();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void insertar() {

        // Extraer datos de UI
        String descripcionNombre = campodescripcionNombre.getText().toString();
        String marca = campoMarca.getText().toString();
        String modelo = campoModelo.getText().toString();
        String correo = campoCorreo.getText().toString();
        String IdentidadObjeto = campoIdObjeto.getText().toString();

        // Validaciones y pruebas de cordura
        if (!esNombreValido(descripcionNombre)) {
            TextInputLayout mascaraCampoNombre = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.mascara_campo_nombre);

            // esta linea la he añadido, si da fallo eliminar. Sujerida por corrector
            assert mascaraCampoNombre != null;
            // esta linea la he añadido, si da fallo eliminar. Sujerida por corrector fin
            mascaraCampoNombre.setError("este campo no puede quedar vacio");
        } else {

            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

            // Verificación: ¿Es necesario generar un id?
            if (uriObjeto == null) {
                valores.put(Objetos.ID_OBJETO, Objetos.generarIdObjeto());
            }
            valores.put(Objetos.DESCRIPCION_NOMBRE, descripcionNombre);
            valores.put(Objetos.MARCA_MARCA, marca);
            valores.put(Objetos.MODELO, modelo);
            valores.put(Objetos.CORREO, correo);
            valores.put(Objetos.VERSION, UTiempo.obtenerTiempo());

            // Iniciar inserción|actualización
            new TareaAnadirObjeto(getContentResolver(), valores).execute(uriObjeto);

            finish();
        }
    }

    private boolean esNombreValido(String nombre) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(nombre);
    }

    private void eliminar() {
        if (uriObjeto != null) {
            // Iniciar eliminación
            new TareaEliminarObjeto(getContentResolver()).execute(uriObjeto);
            finish();
        }
    }


    private void poblarViews(Cursor data) {
        if (!data.moveToNext()) {
            return;
        }

        // Asignar valores a UI
        campodescripcionNombre.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.DESCRIPCION_NOMBRE));
        campoMarca.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.MARCA_MARCA));
        campoModelo.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.MODELO));
        campoCorreo.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.CORREO));
        campoIdObjeto.setText(UConsultas.obtenerString(data, Objetos.ID_OBJETO));

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(this, uriObjeto, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        poblarViews(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if (v == accesodata) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ActividadInsercionObjeto.this, DatosSensor.class);

            i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    static class TareaAnadirObjeto extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {
        private final ContentResolver resolver;
        private final ContentValues valores;

        public TareaAnadirObjeto(ContentResolver resolver, ContentValues valores) {
            this.resolver = resolver;
            this.valores = valores;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... args) {
            Uri uri = args[0];
            if (null != uri) {

                Cursor c = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{Objetos.INSERTADO}, null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {

                    // Verificación de sincronización
                    if (UConsultas.obtenerInt(c, Objetos.INSERTADO) == 0) {
                        valores.put(Objetos.MODIFICADO, 1);
                    }

                    valores.put(Objetos.VERSION, UTiempo.obtenerTiempo());
                    resolver.update(uri, valores, null, null);
                }

            } else {
                resolver.insert(Objetos.URI_CONTENIDO, valores);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    static class TareaEliminarObjeto extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {
        private final ContentResolver resolver;

        public TareaEliminarObjeto(ContentResolver resolver) {
            this.resolver = resolver;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... args) {


            Cursor c = resolver.query(args[0], new String[]{Objetos.INSERTADO}
                    , null, null, null);

            int insertado;

            if (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
                insertado = UConsultas.obtenerInt(c, Objetos.INSERTADO);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            if (insertado == 1) {
                resolver.delete(args[0], null, null);
            } else if (insertado == 0) {
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                valores.put(Objetos.ELIMINADO, 1);
                resolver.update(args[0], valores, null, null);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**Destiny Activity**:

```
public class DatosSensor extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("IdentidadEnviada");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividad_datos_sensor);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idObjeto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        agregarToolbar();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        if (navigationView != null) {
            prepararDrawer(navigationView);
            // Seleccionar item por defecto
            seleccionarItem(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
        }
    }


    private void agregarToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            // Poner ÃƒÂ­cono del drawer toggle
            ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    private void prepararDrawer(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        seleccionarItem(menuItem);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }



    private void seleccionarItem(MenuItem itemDrawer) {
        Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();




        switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {


                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.SaltoWeb.WebOficial.class));
                break;

            //fragmentoGenerico = new BlankFragment();


            case R.id.item_categorias:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.MisSensores.ui.ActividadListaObjeto.class));
                break;

            case R.id.item_acceso:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, com.amg_eservices.appiot.RegistroyAcceso.MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
        if (fragmentoGenerico != null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contenido_principal, fragmentoGenerico)
                    .commit();


        }

        // Setear titulo actual
        setTitle(itemDrawer.getTitle());
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: campoIdObjetoi is a text right?

Comment: xampoIdObjeto is a string. This string was formed in "valores.put(Objetos.ID_OBJETO, Objetos.generarIdObjeto());".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to pass the value of `campoIdObjeto`, so instead of:

```
i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto);
```

write:

```
i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
```

`EditText` is not serialisable, so you can't pass it. But you can pass it's value.

**EDIT**
The second part of @Jordi Castilla answer is the key to get value in the next activity.
You cannot use method `getIntent()` in the static part of the class. Your code:

```
    String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("IdentidadEnviada");
```

inside `DatosSensor` Activity is wrong. Should be invoked inside `onCreate` method or later in the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: OP already takes this value (but does not uses it) in: `String IdentidadObjeto = campoIdObjeto.getText().toString();`

Comment: The value is retrieved in different function. Moreover, there are 2 variables called `IdentidadObjeto` in this code, one class field of type TextView and one of type String inside `onCreate(...)` method. So it is more simple to get the value once again.

Comment: anyway, this won't solve the `NPE` because intent retrieval is not in the right place... this is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the wrong value:

```
i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", (Serializable) campoIdObjeto);  // this is a TextEdit!!!
```

must be

```
i.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", IdentidadObjeto);  // this is the content of TextEdit
```

Also (I might be wrong) but if you call the intent BEFORE `onCreate` event will throw the NPE. So, move this line inside `onCreate()` method

```
String idObjeto = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getStringExtra("IdentidadEnviada");
```

Comment: Also you are right about intent receiver, I had to put it in OnCreate, but the Intent in origin has to be "(Serializable) campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());". Solution from R,Zagórski.

Comment: @OscarC. this is because you assign the variable when it has no value, but if you create `IdentidadObjeto` **use it right or delete it**.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Reference of Edit Text not value of **EditText** and casting value to String with results crashing the app use

```
 intent.putExtra("IdentidadEnviada", campoIdObjeto.getText().toString());
```